# wrong enum value in C#

Tags: c#, enums

Why is the following printing `EOF` as the output and not `ILLEGAL`? If I remove the initialization for EOF to NULL character, it works as expected. Can't understand what is happening here?

```
public enum TokenType {
            ILLEGAL,
            EOF= '\0',//remove the initialization to have it work as expected
            IDENT,
            INT
            };

void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(TokenType.ILLEGAL);//Prints EOF. Should have printed ILLEGAL
}
```

Comment: And what about `Console.WriteLine(Another_TokenType.INT);`?

Comment: What is the value of `(int)TokenType.ILLEGAL`, and of `(int)TokenType.EOF`?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yeah. I just tested with that and removed that example

Comment: Character `'\0'` is the same as integer 0. Looks like both ILLEGAL and EOF have the value 0. You can try to assign values to each or none of your enum elements.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum

Comment: for those of you playing along at home https://dotnetfiddle.net/UHFeuL

Comment: @SomeBody yeah. I understand that it is same as 0 underneath. And in this particular case, it seems that once you specify a explicit value for a enum member, you should explicitly specify values for all other members as well. Otherwise you will get 'undefined' behaviour. msdn doco doesn't seem to make this point clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that `= '\0'` is the same as `= 0`. This is because`'\0'` has the numerical value of 0. Your enum has the default underlying type of `int`. The constant expression `'\0'` is converted to the `int` of `0` at compile time.

Second, as per the [language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums#enum-members), note that enum members can have duplicated associated values.

Third, from the the same section of the language spec,

> The associated value of an enum member is assigned either implicitly
> or explicitly. [...] If the declaration of the enum member has no
> initializer, its associated value is set implicitly, as follows:
>
> - If the enum member is the first enum member declared in the enum type, its associated value is zero.
> - Otherwise, the associated value of the enum member is obtained by increasing the associated value of the textually preceding enum member
>   by one. This increased value must be within the range of values that
>   can be represented by the underlying type, otherwise a compile-time
>   error occurs.

So if I were to write out your enum's members' associated values explicitly, it would be:

```
public enum TokenType {
        ILLEGAL = 0,
        EOF = 0,
        IDENT = 1,
        INT = 2
        };
```

`ILLEGAL` and `EOF` have the same associated value.

Fourth, `Console.WriteLine` calls `ToString` on your enum. Now look at what [`Enum.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?view=netcore-3.1) does (in the Notes to Callers section):

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you
> attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration
> member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make
> any assumptions about which name the method will return.

So, it outputting `ILLEGAL` is completely normal, as you "should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return".

Answer (score 5):

By initializing the `EOF` value with '\0' you give it a value of `0`.

You can see this in this example:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt16(TokenType.EOF));
Console.WriteLine($"IntValue: {Convert.ToInt16('\0')}");
```

> 0
> IntValue: 0

Internally the enum will get values starting from 0 on counting upwards in integers. So below the surface your enum looks like this:

```
public enum TokenType
{
    ILLEGAL = 0,
    EOF = 1
    IDENT = 2,
    INT = 3
};
```

But you chose to enforce a `0` on the value `EOF`! So you have 2 enum names representing the same value. The compiler simply takes the first one that it can find.

Answer (score 1):

this explains the siutation

```
foreach (Enum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TokenType)))
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e, Convert.ToInt16(e));

Console.WriteLine();

foreach (Enum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Another_TokenType)))
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e, Convert.ToInt16(e));


EOF: 0
EOF: 0
IDENT: 1
INT: 2

ILLEGAL: 0
ILLEGAL: 0
EOF: 1
IDENT: 2
```

'\0' leads to value 0 when converted to int. and the first non-value initialized enum flag has also value 0.

Comment: why does your answer not display ILLEGAL in first output and INT in second output?

Comment: @DurgaPrasad It's documented that It's not guaranteed which one it will output. See the last part of my answer.

Comment: I see. I was under the impression that foreach will iterate through all the values in given enum including the duplicates as well so they have to be printed in that order. As per your answer, it does iterate through duplicate values, however the string value associated with the duplicate enum can be either of them.

Comment: @DurgaPrasad All the values are indeed iterated through. It's just that `ToString` can't distinguish between the two "different" 0s. If you want to get all the names you could always use [`GetNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=netcore-3.1).